# Carousel change with mouse wheel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mouse, carousel

I'm trying to make my carousel go to the next picture when I scroll up but when I scroll down go back.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#this-carousel-id').bind('mousewheel', function(e){$(this).carousel('next');});
</script>
```

This code works for scroll up for the next picture but doesn't work to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest example but this should work:

```
$('#this-carousel-id').bind('mousewheel', function(e)
    {
        if(event.wheelDelta>0) {
            $(this).carousel('next');
        }else if(event.wheelDelta<0){
            $(this).carousel('prev');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm trying something similar using most of your logic and it doesn't respond at all to the bound event logic. I have it up here http://www.bootply.com/EASRyUFp5P